# Use an external framework in a Qt application targetting iOS

Tags: ios, qt, qt-creator, ios-frameworks

I am trying to do something really easy but I cannot find any example/documentation about that unfortunately.
I have a working Qt application that I deploy to iOS using a pro file and QtCreator. Everything works fine at that point.
I try to include an external Framework, and I add the following lines (well I use the QtCreator UI that generates them to be more accurate) to my pro file:

```
LIBS += -F$$PWD/../../../../thirdparty/aws-ios-sdk-2/frameworks/ -framework AWSS3

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../thirdparty/aws-ios-sdk-2/frameworks
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../thirdparty/aws-ios-sdk-2/frameworks
```

I can compile, but when I try to run the app in the simulator I get a:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AWSS3.framework/AWSS3.
```

I found many people complaining about this kind of issue that got fixed by changing a "embedded binaries" settings in Xcode. But:

- I cannot find this settings in Xcode 7
- I would like to use only QtCreator if that is possible

Any clue ?

Thanks !

Comment: I found this on Qt forum, but I am not sure what it means:
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51951